# Custom Pattern Fills in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to be able to add my own custom pattern fills for projects I am working on in Excel 2013.  For example, I would like to have a brick-like pattern, and a horizontal hash line pattern.

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to create custom pattern fills to be used in Excel 2013?

Answer (score 1):

After researching this I don't think it is possible I found nothing that allows this and it probably would not be allowed as others opening the file wouldn't have the custom fill patterns.

An idea I had was to replace the cell contents with a image based on a value but the VBA I found was very befuddled and hard to understand I did however find that you can use following to insert images into to the cells based on a value

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1858-excel-insert-image-based-on-cell-value.html

I have used other items they produce before and they are reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, this won't work in my situation.

Comment: No problem if you are able to find a solution let us know I'm very interested. You are allowed to  answer your own question!